# CSS is not loading when using segment URI in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, uri

why CSS is not loading when using segment URI in codeigniter
but it is working good when I remove the segment ?

[image: not_loading]

this is how I link the css file

```
<title>TITLE</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link href="public/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
<!-- //bootstrap -->
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="public/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />

<script src="public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class profiles extends CI_Controller
{

        public function index()
{      
        $user_id = $this->uri->segment(2, 9);

        $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('count_model');
              $data   = array();


    $result =  $this->user_model->read_user_information_profile($user_id);        

     $data = array(
    'username' => $result[0]->username,
    'fname' => $result[0]->fname,
    'lname' => $result[0]->lname,

        );
    $this->load->view('profiles_view', $data);
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us how you're linking your CSS?

Comment: show your code, PHP, HTML, CSS. How else are we suppose to know your problem?

Comment: @CodeGodie check it now

Comment: you are not using a base_url()

Comment: @HeshamWatany , do you get it now? Jason provided a great answer

Comment: working good now thanks <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using relative URLs for loading your CSS, it's trying to load it from /dir/profiles/public/css/style.css instead of /dir/public/css/style.css hence why it doesn't load.

You can either use absolute URLs in your CSS with:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('public/css/style.css'); ?>" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
```

Or set a base tag before you try to load any CSS or JS:

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
```

See: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url, note you may need to load the URL helper if you're not already.

Comment: and where do you set `site_url()`?

Comment: It comes from the URL helper. Better to use base_url() instead. Post edited.

Comment: Good. Docs here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Answer (score 0):

Change the loading in this way:

```
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
<!-- //bootstrap -->
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="<?php echo base_ur;(); ?>css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

You don't need to config the `base_url`. It detect automatically